# Json phonegap return result

Tags: jquery, json, cordova

I'm making a phonegap app for iphone and android.
my code works fine in browsers but when i tried with phonegap, the phone displays the json result and do not excute the code in the submit fonction, here is a picture of what i got when i click on the submit button :
http://i48.tinypic.com/21l1km0.png
I used $ajax() and json.eval() but i got the same result,

```
form.onsubmit = function()
{
    var formData = new FormData(form);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        url: 'http://server.com',
        success: function(data){
            console.log("wa3 1");
            alert('Your comment was successfully added');
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log("wa3 2");
            alert('There was an error adding your comment');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I found the solution, It is very simple, I added the type of the data : `dataType:'json',` .

Comment: AJAX doesn't require any static Web 1.0 forms - that's yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

I think the ajax call is not executed. The submit button sends the form but not with ajax.
So you are redirected to the server script page.

To prevent this behavior, add `return false;` in your event onsubmit.

This code will prevent your html page to send the form. So the ajax function could send the datas.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention it but I'm using return false; So the problem is not there.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the syntax to the following:

```
$('#myform').on ('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault ();
    //rest of your code
});
```

Or add

```
return false;
```

At the end of the onsubmit function.

Comment: I tried to do like you said but nothing changed, Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have not set the encoding of your php script :

Add this line at the top of your script :

```
<?php header('Content-type: application/json'); ?>
```

Comment: I think phoneGap does not support php yet

Comment: Yeah I know, but I thaught your target script was out of your application